# What is the difference between these whitespaces?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have 2 queries as below. But only the second one return the results.

The white space in query 1 I typed from my computer and in query 2 I copy from the data. What is the differences between them?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 like ' %';

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 like ' %';
```

---

Thanks GreenLake4964. I attached the inspected code in Chrome for 2 queries above.

[image: Inspect in Chrome]

Comment: Are you using PHPMyAdmin by any change, when "*typed from computer*" ??

Comment: I typed in Mysql Workbench.

Comment: 'I copy from the data' - is the difference - data must contain non printing characters which only look like white space. Can you add the data to the question?

Comment: You can take look the white space in 2 queries above. When I paste them to Stack Overflow it still be the difference characters.

Comment: `SELECT col1, HEX(col1) FROM table1`  -- so we can see what "whitespace" is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a tool such as UltraEditor or Notepad++, 
paste your sql statement there and convert from "ASCII to Hex",
then you should be able to see the differences.

Alternatively, the DB you are using might have a ASCII to hex conversion feature (or similar) that you can find out the exact character you are using.

Comment: Oh thank you. When I convert these characters to Hex the first character is '20' and the second is 'a0'. I see the differences behind the scenes.